Ping is way too slow
I have 167 IPs to ping. I set timeout to 100ms or 1ms no matter what I set, I async/await, without async/await, with Task.Run() all about the same result of approximately 80 seconds!
List<PingResult> res = new List<PingResult>();
var model = await _toyCityService.GetToyCityViewModel();
foreach (var item in model)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DevIPWIFI))
    {
        bool? pingable = false;

        try
        {
            PingReply reply = await Task.Run(() => new Ping().SendPingAsync(item.DevIPWIFI,100));
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                long LastDateTimeRec = (item.LastDateTimeRec == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt64(item.LastDateTimeRec));
                var timeMinusFive = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5).ToFileTime();
                if (timeMinusFive < LastDateTimeRec)
                    pingable = true;
                else
                    pingable = null;
            }
            else
            {
                pingable = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            pingable = false;
        }
        res.Add(new PingResult()
        {
            Id = item.ID,
            IP = item.DevIPWIFI,
            Status = pingable
        });
    }
}
return res;

I have tested with these:
PingReply reply = await new Ping().SendPingAsync(item.DevIPWIFI,100);
PingReply reply = new Ping().Send(item.DevIPWIFI,100);
PingReply reply = await Task.Run(() => new Ping().SendPingAsync(item.DevIPWIFI,100,buffer,pingOptions));
I have to mention the time taken is from foreach start point until return and from these 167 IPs, most of them like 160 of them gets timeout and I am aware of it!
but I set timeout to 1ms and 100ms. let's say 100, so at worst scenario, It should take about 20 Seconds not 80 to 100 seconds! You can test that with 160 IPs at your network that get timeout.
I also put a breakpoint on PingReply to see how is everything going, and everything goes fine and fast! All the code not just ping itself.
Now calculate for 1ms! It shouldn't take even a second.
I am using the latest VS2022, Dotnet SDK 8.0.5, and ASP.Net Core MVC.

I think you're sequentially waiting for all the Pings to be completed, instead if just firing all of them and see when all finished. Having said his, instead of await eb´very task in your loop, build a List<Task> and add the task to be awaited oneach iteration. Afterwards call Task.WhenAll and await that.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain thanks for ur respond but I mentioned that I also use it without await, so it should fire and go. and if I even set await, why should it stay on that IP for more than the timeout I set? Is it a dotnet problem?

await Task.Run(() => new Ping().SendPingAsync is pointless. The operation is already asynchronous. Task.Run just returns the inner task too, so Task.Run just adds a tiny delay in this case.

I think your problem is that you're sequentially awaiting every single task. So when you have 100 tasks, you're effectivly firing the second one after the first finishes.
What you seem to need instead, is to fire all these tasks simultaneously and wait for all of them to finish. To achieve that, add every task to a List<Task> and use await Task.WhenAll:
var list = new List<Task>();
foreach(var m in model)
{
    list.Add(new Ping().SendAsync(...));  // no await here
}
await Task.WhenAll(list);  // await all tasks

or a strongly-typed version:
var list = new List<Task<PingReply>>();
foreach(var m in model)
{
    list.Add(new Ping().SendAsync(...));  // no await here
}
var replies = await Task.WhenAll(list);  // await all tasks


I test it now and let you know the result

No, It didn't help and from var list = new List<Task>(); to await Task.WhenAll(list); Takes a lot of time.

It isn't duplicate question :| I Saw that question before I ask this. these two are different. and even I need those IPs and the result of each one separately.

@AliJebali did you omit await insode the loop? Actually your loop should be incredibly fast, as you're not awaiting any of the tasks inside.

for testing your answer, I put your code exactly on top of my foreach and test it by breakpoint. It takes even more time about 110 seconds! I know this is weird, that is why I ask it here.
